# term for things centered around a person

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I my work group often the decisions taken are heavily influenced by "becky", because she talks more..., is it correct to say that the group is 'beckycentric', i am looking for a term to describe that most of the time the decisions are her wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"-centric" is a common suffix that means exactly what you are looking for:

> [-centric](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Centric) — a combining form with the meanings “having a center or centers” of the specified number or kind (polycentric ); “centered upon, focused around” that named by the first element (ethnocentric; heliocentric).

Used in your context it typically takes a hyphen because is a non-standard word and it makes the "ckyc" pattern in the middle easier to read on first glance:

> Our group is too Becky-centric.

Comment: alright, looks logically-centric. Thanks